# Infinite sets: Equipotent sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the next theorem about equipotents sets.

If $A$ $ \approx$ $B$ and $C$ $\approx$ $D$ and suppose that $A$ $\cap$ $C$ $=$ $\emptyset$ and $B$ $\cap$ $D$ $=$ $\emptyset$ then $A$ $\cup$ $C$ $\approx$ $B$ $\cup$ $D$

I was trying to proof it and this is my progress:

$\exists$ $f$: $A$ $\to$ $B$ bijective 
$x$ $\mapsto$ $f(x)$

$\exists$ $g$: $C$ $\to$ $D$ bijective 
$x$ $\mapsto$ $g(x)$

Define $h: A \cup C \to B \cup D$ by

$$ h(x) = \begin{cases} 
 f(x) & \text{if } x \in A \\  
 g(x) & \text{if } x \in C\\ 
 \end{cases} 
$$
We should prove that it is a function, injective and surjective. It's correct? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems like a great start. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Let $ d,d'$ $ \in$ dom( $f$ $\cup$ $g$) To prove that is a function it is correct? more specific how I take the elements and where I arrive @Vsotvep

Comment: I suggest to look up the definition of a function and see if $f\cup g$ satisfies it (most notably, does *every* element in the domain have *exactly one* function value in the range)

Comment: By the way, my advice from one of your previous questions still holds: try to write some actual sentences in your proof, instead of only symbols. Only symbols generally isn't acceptable as an (informal) proof; a proof should be more like an explanation, where you try to convince the reader of the truth of your statement. A well written proof can be pronounced out loud and still be understandable.

Comment: Sus sugerencias son evidentes e importantes lo que pasa es que a veces se me dificulta escribir en inglés por mi idioma, podrías darme alguna idea de como empezar la demostración para que sea función , la verdad no tengo claro si tomo un elemento $d$ $\in$  $f$ $\cup$ $g$ entonces existe un elemento $e$ ... @Vsotvep

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to include the definitions of "function", "injective" and "surjective", and show us how far you get with proving that $f\cup g$ satisfies these definitions. Otherwise there isn't much I could help with, the only way to learn how to write proofs is by doing it a lot. And broken English is fine, but a proof *really* needs words like "because", "therefore", and definitions / assumptions like "let $x$ be ..." or "assume that ...".

Comment: Thanks, I will try it @ Vsotvep

Comment: It's a function because the subdomains are disjoint. Injectiveness is clear because the image sets $B$ and $D$ are disjoint too, and $f,g$ are already injective.

Comment: 1. Sea un elemento  $x$ que pertenece al dominio de $f$ entonces existe un $y$ tal que el par ordenado $(x,y)$ pertenece a $f$, esto es $(x,y)$ pertenece a al producto cruz de $AxB$, por lo tanto $x$ pertenece a $A$.2 Sea un elemento $x$ que pertenece a $A$ entonces existe un $y$ que pertenece a $B$ tal que el par ordenado $(x,y)$ pertenece a $f$ esto es $x$ pertenece al dominio de $f$. 3. Sea un elemento $y$ que pertenece al recorrido de $f$ entonces existe un elemento $x$ tal que el par ordenado $(x,y)$ pertenece a $f$, esto es $(x,y)$ pertenece a $AxB$, por lo tanto $y$ $\in$ $B$ @Vsotvep

Comment: De forma similar para $g$ ? y luego concluir que $h$ es una función ? @Vsotvep

Comment: Your deduction is because $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions but what happen with $h(x)$? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @Jason that $h$ is surjective should be clear. If $h(x)=h(y)$ distinguish the cases that this common image is in $B$ or $D$.

Comment: $h(A\cup C) = h(A) \cup h(C)= f(A) \cup g(C) = B \cup D$ this show tha $h$ is surjective.  what would your demonstration be?@HennoBrandsma

Comment: What do you think about proof $h$ is a function? @Vsotvep

Comment: @Jason, I don't think you've given a proof that $h$ is a function, you didn't even mention $h$ in what you've written above. It reads to me that you showed that if $f(x)=y$, then $(x,y)\in f$, which is not something that needs to be proved. I'll suggest once more to [edit] your question and add the *definitions* of what a "function" is, what "injective" is and what "surjective" is. I also suggest that you add your proof attempt to the question by [edit]. The comments should be used for clarification, but not to state your question itself.